# Find correct cell value, given conditions, in large data frames

Tags: r

I have two large data frames, say df1 and df2. I want to add one value, given certain conditions, to df2.

df2 contains pepole - ie:

```
> df2
  ID Age Gender
1  1  20      M
2  2  30      K
3  3  40      M
4  4  60      M
```

Then i have df1 which contains lots of infmation, one number for each age from 0 to 100 and for each gender. I need to find the korrekt number for my person. Say i look up age 30 i get

```
> df1[df1[,'V10'] == 30,]
    V5 V10  V12
31   K  30 5.91
151  M  30 5.33
```

In df2 i want the value 5.91 since my persen is female. Like this

```
> df1[df1[,'V10'] == 30 &
+       df1[,'V5'] == 'K', 'V12']
[1] 5.91
```

First I tried this in a for-loop, but it takes too long. Then i tried with()

```
df2$number <- with(df2, df1[df1[,'V10'] == Age &
                              df1[,'V5'] == Gender, 'V12'])
```

but i only gives me one value for all of them.

Hope some of you understand my problem, and can help me. My main problem is that run time is too long.

Comment: Have you tried [merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)?

Comment: No, but i'm going to try that now! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As it was stated in a comment, you could use `merge` to get the value of `V12` for each gender and age.

I created some dummy data to show how it could be done.

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID = 1:6,
              Age = c(20,30,40, 40, 60, 60),
              Gender = c("M","K","M", "K", "M", "K"))

df1 <- data.frame(V5 = rep(c("K", "M"), 41),
              V10 = rep(20:60, each= 2),
              V12 = runif(82, 1,10))

df <- merge(df2, df1, by.x=c("Age", "Gender"), by.y=c("V10", "V5"))
```

With the `merge()` function, you can merge on more than one column by specifying the column names  within the `by` argument.

`by.x` its used for the columns of the first `data.frame` used as input (`df2` in this case) and `by.y` for the column names of `df1`.

If you prefer, you could use `left_join` from the `dplyr` package. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right) stackoverflow post.